# Post excerpt in Wordpress widget?

Tags: wordpress, post, widget

I would like to embed excerpt of the latest post from a specific category into a WP widget, with its background being the featured image, and I was wondering; if anybody knows how it's done, would you please care to explain?

To help you guys understand better, this is how I'm imagining the HTML to look:

`<div style="background-image: url(featured image link);">Content from latest post in category X</div>`

Comment: provide your code if you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something like this in your widget code:

`<?php
  $x_cat_id = get_cat_ID('X');
  $widget_post = get_posts(array('category'=>$x_cat_id, 'numberposts'=>1)); //get last post from category X
  $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($widget_post->ID); //get thumbnail id to retrieve all the data we'll need
  ?>
  <div style="background-image: url(<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($post_thumbnail_id); ?>);"><?php print $widget_post->post_excerpt; ?></div>`